# how to access 2nd array in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array returned from a json, I can access the values from one part of the array, but I can't access the values from another part of the array

```
echo '<strong>Barcode Number:</strong> ' . $response->products[0]->barcode_number . '<br><br>';

echo '<strong>Product Name:</strong> ' . $response->products[0]->product_name . '<br><br>';

echo '<strong>Description:</strong> ' . $response->products[0]->description . '<br><br>';

echo '<strong>Description:</strong> ' . $response->stores[0]->store_name . '<br><br>';
```

I get the first three fine but the last one for stores returns the error

> Barcode Number: 077341125112
>
> Product Name: Custom Accessories 89960W E-Tek Butane Torch
>
> Description: Butane Torch, 89960W is ideal for your home garage or
>   your car. Can be used for quick repairs.
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$stores in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\customs\production\test-barcodelookup.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'store_name' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\customs\production\test-barcodelookup.php on line 20

```
$ch = curl_init(); // Use only one cURL connection for multiple queries

$data = get_data($url, $ch);

$response = array();
$response = json_decode($data);

echo '<strong>Barcode Number:</strong> ' . $response->products[0]->barcode_number . '<br><br>';

echo '<strong>Product Name:</strong> ' . $response->products[0]->product_name . '<br><br>';

echo '<strong>Description:</strong> ' . $response->products[0]->description . '<br><br>';

echo '<strong>Description:</strong> ' . $response->stores[0]->store_name . '<br><br>';



echo '<strong>Entire Response:</strong><pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';

   function get_data($url, $ch) {

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);

     return $data;
 }
```

Below is the array returned

Entire Response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [barcode_number] => 077341125112
                    [barcode_type] => UPC
                    [barcode_formats] => UPC 077341125112, EAN 0077341125112
                    [mpn] => 0007734112511
                    [model] => 89960w
                    [asin] => 
                    [product_name] => Custom Accessories 89960W E-Tek Butane Torch
                    [title] => 
                    [category] => Hardware > Tools > Hardware Torches
                    [manufacturer] => 
                    [brand] => Etek
                    [label] => 
                    [author] => 
                    [publisher] => 
                    [artist] => 
                    [actor] => 
                    [director] => 
                    [studio] => 
                    [genre] => 
                    [audience_rating] => 
                    [ingredients] => 
                    [nutrition_facts] => 
                    [color] => 
                    [format] => 
                    [package_quantity] => 
                    [size] => 
                    [length] => 
                    [width] => 
                    [height] => 
                    [weight] => 
                    [release_date] => 
                    [description] => Butane Torch, 89960W is ideal for your home garage or your car.  Can be used for quick repairs.
                    [features] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://images.barcodelookup.com/3001/30014169-1.jpg
                        )

                    [stores] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [store_name] => Wal-Mart.com USA, LLC
                                    [store_price] => 14.97
                                    [product_url] => http://www.walmart.com/ip/Custom-Accessories-89960W-E-Tek-Butane-Torch/29029306
                                    [currency_code] => USD
                                    [currency_symbol] => $
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [store_name] => Jet.com
                                    [store_price] => 14.20
                                    [product_url] => http://jet.com/product/detail/a43035df304c4551b45f62262402f9f2
                                    [currency_code] => USD
                                    [currency_symbol] => $
                                )

                        )

                    [reviews] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Ken Weber
                                    [rating] => 5
                                    [title] => Torch Performance
                                    [review] => I didnt know  how good this torch was until I used it and its very nice for the money. The electronic ignition fires the butane evertime. Nice feel to it. Has a trigger lock down for extended usage time.  GOOD PRODUCT.
                                    [datetime] => 2015-12-29 11:27:34
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to access the images array and echo it out and the information from the stores array and echo it. I can get the information from the products array. but I can't figure out how to get the others

This is what I am trying to achieve

> Barcode Number: 077341125112
>
> Product Name: Custom Accessories 89960W E-Tek Butane Torch
>
> Description: Butane Torch, 89960W is ideal for your home garage or
>   your car. Can be used for quick repairs.
>
> Display Image of product.
>
> Stores:
>
> store_name: Wal-Mart.com USA, LLC store_price:  14.97 product_url:
>   http://www.walmart.com/ip/Custom-Accessories-89960W-E-Tek-Butane-Torch/29029306
>
> store_name: Jet.com store_price:  14.20 product_url:
>   http://jet.com/product/detail/a43035df304c4551b45f62262402f9f2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you format the data, it shows that the stores data is under each product, so you would need to display it as...

```
$response->products[0]->stores[0]->store_name
```

You would also probably need to use a `foreach()` to display all the details, both with products and the stores for each product.

```
foreach ( $response->products[0]->stores as $store )  {
    // Echo out the details
    echo $store->store_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Side-step: I think the easiest way to go about this process is using

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

This makes everything an associative array.

Here is the [manual for the json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  internal function.

Step-back:

```
$response->products[0]->stores[0]->store_name
```